# Subclass of UIView with storyboard

Tags: objective-c, xcode

If you want to display some UIViews as content in a subview, you can make classes for the UIViews and add an XIBs for them. Then these UIViews can be displayed in a subview in a UIViewController. But with storyboard, how to set up an interface for a UIView to use as a subview, without making it in a UIViewController??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is, you don't. If your views are completely re-usable and can be fully de-coupled from any View Controller, feel free to continue using .xib files for these.

Storyboards are intended to architect and document the UI at the level of "hierarchies of views", each hierarchy is managed by a view controller. Xib files are still be right place to construct (graphically) "satellite" views which do not belong to a particular view hierarchy.

Comment: Ok, so I can make a `UIView` class with XIB and use this to populate the subview, even with storyboard?

Comment: A xib can be thought of as a *container* full of views (instances of objects which extend UIView). You can use storyboards for your app's primary UI, and then have a XIB with a collection of related re-usable views. You will need to use a pinch of code to load the xib and find the view in it (many choose to have 1 view per xib, making this much easier). See here: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UINib_Ref/Reference/Reference.html After instantiating, you essentially have an NSArray of all the "top level" view objects in the xib.